# Is it safe to use a PHP_SELF value in a header redirect?

Tags: php

i.e. store it in a session, and then when the user logs in, redirect to that page?

```
$_SESSION['last_page'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];    
//(in a common file on all pages)
```

and then after logging in:

```
header('location: ' . $_SESSION['last_page']);`
```

I'm wondering because I read that people can modify the values of certain keys in `$_SERVER`

Would it be better to use `SCRIPT_NAME` instead or is `PHP_SELF` fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be used for XSS vulnerables.

Don't risk it and use

```
 $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
```

instead.

Comment: what makes `SCRIPT_NAME` safer than `PHP_SELF`? from what I understand, `PHP_SELF` is the requested page, and `SCRIPT_NAME` is the actual page (i.e. if page1.php is redirected to page2.php)

Comment: This is not that easy to explain. Here you can find all about it:
http://www.webadminblog.com/index.php/2010/02/23/a-xss-vulnerability-in-almost-every-php-form-ive-ever-written/ - $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; is the only safe way.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be giving a relative path/URL for the Location when setting an HTTP header, specify the full URL to the script.

```
$_SESSION['last_page'] = "http://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
header('Location: ' . $_SESSION['last_page']);
```

The difference between `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` & `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` is that `PHP_SELF` "remembers" any information specified after the reference to the PHP script in the URL. If you don't need this extra information, just use `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions variables cannot be trusted directly. They are considered *user input* just like GET or POST variables. Therefore I suggest you to list a number of possibilities (or alternatively use a REGEX) to test if `$_SESSION['last_page']` is valid, before use it, *especially* in a redirect.

Comment: What do you think about `filter_var($_SESSION['last_page'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` - then if the user makes it redirect to a rogue site, it would only affect them?

Comment: @cantsay, it just validates a URI, you should check if it's valid for your logic. It's likely that you have a very limited number of script names that can be executed in the server. Why don't you just list them in an array and check if `$_SESSION['last_page']` is in that array?